# Как включить подсказки для Unity в Visual studio?

Tags: unity3d

Так как в версии 18 года любимую MonoDevelop больше не поддерживают, придется пользоваться VS. Все будет ничего, но подсказок как в моно нет, вернее есть но команд юнити там нет (Time, touch, PlayerPrefs и все остальное), как их включить? В VS code тоже их нет

Comment: Хороший вопрос! Поддержу

Comment: Странно, у меня с установки, когда я пишу код с подключённым автоматом Unity неймспейсом UnityEngine, все подсказки отображаются.

Answer (score 9):

Всё до банальности просто, достаточно установить расширения для Visual Studio для этого прожмите:

1. *Средства -> Расширения и обновления...* *(Tools -> Extentions and Updates..)*
2. В появившемся окне вбить в поисковике **Unity**.
3. Установить расширение. *(Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Unity)*

   Но по идее без него должно было всё работать, вроде бы.

Answer (score 4):

В Unity надо открыть: Edit -> Preferences, вкладка External Tools, в External Script Editor выбирать: Visual Studio 2017 Community.

[См.документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 3):

Была такая же проблема при использовании VSCode в юнити 2019.2.11f, т.е. не отображались контекстные подсказки при вводе для классов, методов и т.д.

Как решил:
1) Делаем все в точности как описано в официальном мануале по интеграции VSCode с Unity 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

2) Если все сделали по мануалу, у вас должен быть установлен VSCode с плагинами C# и Debugger for Unity, при этом в юнити в Edit\Preferences\External tools у вас выставлен VSCode(с установленными параметрами ProjectPath, File, Line, Column) как редактор скриптов и установлен флажок Editor Attaching. Далее, открываем любой скрипт из юнити - 
 он должен открыться в VSCode и в окне Explorer-а должна отображаться вся структура вашего проекта( а не только файл открытого скрипта).

3)Плагин C# внутри VSCode должен выдать предупреждение в лог (консоль можно открыть в самом нижнем поле редактора VSCode слева внизу два значка - ошибка и предупреждение), что файл проекта подгружен некорректно из-за отсутствия необходимого пакета .Net Framework какой-либо версии (в моем случае это была версия 4.7.1, в вашем случае может быть другая)! Устанавливаем требуемый пакет .NET Framework с оф. сайта майкрософта (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework) или откуда угодно, ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ УСТАНОВЛЕНА БОЛЕЕ ПОЗДНЯЯ ВЕРСИЯ (это никак не повредит ей).

После установки .Net Framework закройте на всякий случай Unity(если изменяли состояние флажка Editor attaching) и VSCode. Откройте юнити заново и откройте любой скрипт. В этот раз при открытии файла плагин C# в VSCode больше не должен выдавать ошибок загрузки проекта и контекстные подсказки будут работать.

P.S. дополнение VSCode integration для Unity из Asset Store можно не устанавливать, т.к. если все сделано правильно, то все работает и без него.

Answer (score 0):

надо просто поставить галочку в unityhab 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2019

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]